# Nuxt3 content v2 breaks on page refresh on netlify when site is statically generated

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I built a blog with nuxt content v2 and everything works on my machine. I ran `npm run generate` and `npm run preview` and everything works as expected.  The problem is that when using netlify, I have the build command set to `npm run generate` and the site deploys and works, but in the blog post page I get an error on refresh and the page goes blank.

If I set the netlify build command to `npm run build` then this no longer happens but the contact form from netlify no longer works, this is the main reason I was using the `npm run generate` command.

Do note that it does work when the user navigates to a blog post, but in the case the user refreshes everything breaks.

the error says: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'author')`

This only happens when the page is refreshed, and the reason it happens is on refresh there is a fetch request sent out to:
`/api/_content/query/bNC8phj644.1679318873303.json?_params=%7B%22where%22:%5B%7B%22_path%22:%22/blog/posts/first-blog/%22%7D%5D,%22first%22:true,%22sort%22:%5B%7B%22_file%22:1,%22$numeric%22:true%7D%5D%7D`

I am a bit confused why this is happening because I thought when the `npm run generate` command is ran it pulls in the data, and I was under the assumption that the static site no longer needs to fetch data.

#### `[...slug].vue`

The data is all here, but on refresh a fetch request is sent out and this should not be happening since fetch should only run and pull in data at build time since `npm run generate` is being used. This happens below in the blog post list component but here on each page refresh a fetch request is sent out and there shouldn't be.

```html
<script setup>
const { path } = useRoute()

const { data: blogPost } = await useAsyncData(`content-${path}`, () => {
  return queryContent().where({ _path: path }).findOne()
})
</script>

<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="author-name">{{ blogPost.author.firstName }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### `/content/blog/posts/first-blog.md`

```
---
author: {
  firstName: 'david'
}
---
```

The thing that gets me is if we move up a little bit, I built a `<BlogPostList />` component. And the code inside it looks like this.
Here everything works perfectly, in `[...slug].vue` the same thing is being done yet it breaks on refresh in netlify. Could this be due to a dynamic route?

#### `<BlogPostList />`

Here the same thing is essentially being done and nothing breaks. Also when I go to this component and look at the network tab, on page refresh there is no fetch request being sent out. Yet the same thing does not happen in `[...slug].vue`. It makes me wonder if this is some bug or due to the fact the route is dynamic.

```html
<script setup>

const { data: blogPostList } = await useAsyncData('blogPostList', () => {
  return queryContent('/blog/posts').find()
})

</script>

<template>
  <div class="blog-post-container">
    <template v-for="(blogPost, index) in blogPostList" :key="index">
      <div class="post">
        <div>{{ blogPost.author.firstName }}</div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens to me. But I do not use `npm run generate`, I use `yarn build` for building website.

I think it is due to dynamic route, because on page refresh all html from `[slug].vue` disappeares.

```
<main class="relative overflow-hidden" data-v-23a393d3=""><!--[--><!----><!--]--></main>
```

[all code regarding slug page disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV3rX.jpg)

Honestly, I don't know what happens..

UPD. The issue was found. It is because of trailing slashes. Thanks to [this answer from theo](https://answers.netlify.com/t/nuxt-content-api-results-in-404-error/79299/2).

```
// remove trailing slash from path
const actualPath = route.path.replace(/\/$/, '');

const { data } = await useAsyncData(`content-${actualPath}`, () =>
    queryContent(actualPath).findOne()
);
```

Comment: The trailing slash was the issue, this does not require regex, it was actually coming from netlify‘s post build settings